# CSS for a Bootstrap 4 button does not work when applied, why?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I just started creating my first Bootstrap project. However, my CSS for my Bootstrap button does not work. It is not applied. I wonder why, because it worked in the past.

I just want to set my button to green. This is my button (I am talking about the blue one):

[image]

Here is my code:

```css
   button {
        padding-top: 200px;
        background-color: #388E3C;  
    }
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-lg-6" id="function2">
            <div class="input-group" id="input">
                <div class="custom-file">
                  <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01"
                    aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
                  <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose your p12 file...</label>
                </div>
            </div>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Convert p12 to jks</button> <!-- This is the button! -->

        </div>
  
    </div>
```

I use the padding to check if anything is applied. I appreciate every kind of help.

Comment: Probably fails in terms of specificity compared to Bootstrap's CSS. Also do you load your CSS before or after Bootstrap?

Comment: What do you mean? The blue color is also by me, I just cannot change the color anymore. My style css comes after bootstraps css

Comment: @AndroidAnton there are multiple ways to fix it, either you can create a `selector` class(I answered it below) and assign the property so that it will work or you should inherit from the parent then the selector.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are that Boostrap's CSS file is overriding yours, ensure that you load your CSS file after the Boostrap one. You'd be best assigning a custom class to the button

```
<button id="customButton" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Convert p12 to jks</button>
```

Then setting your CSS to

```
button#customButton {
padding-top: 200px;
background-color: #388E3C;  
}
```

Comment: `!important` should be the last option since it overrides all the values, this may not be the best answer!.

Comment: Thank you, but my style.css loads after bootstraps. I will try your solution in few minutes and give feedback

Comment: @Manjuboyz That's true - Maybe best to apply a class or id to that button to stop it overriding the whole stylesheet. Looks like you beat me to it!

Comment: hahaha nothing such bro! I don't ever use `important` as a property, cheers to that you agreed !

Comment: Thank you, the !important does its job but I will check to make it cleaner

Comment: @AndroidAnton `!important` may solve the issue, I am not against @Alex's answer but it is not the best answer in the list! you shouldn't use this snippet in your code!.

Comment: @Alex you may curse me! lol but your code will not work now, at-least it works for `!important` but not now! Kindly use this `button#customButton` (remove space in-between).

Comment: @Manjuboyz Oh for goodness me! Hahah! That's what I get for trying to do two things at once...

Comment: Happens! happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

It's definitely an specificity problem,

You are targeting just `button` elements, which is less *specific* than a class, that's why you style isn't applying and is being overwritten by bootstrap's class.

Either add your own class to the button to apply your styles, or target the button + a bootstrap class.

I would advise against using `!important`, it is not really necessary

```css
button.btn {
  padding-top: 200px;
  background-color: #388E3C;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="function2">
      <div class="input-group" id="input">
        <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose your p12 file...</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Convert p12 to jks</button>
      <!-- This is the button! -->

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can solve it in multiple ways

1. Use `button.btn {....}` than `button {....}` this should take care of your issue.
2. Use a `selector` class for the button then assign the property(which is what I have done).

```css
#cssBtn {
  padding-top: 200px;
  background-color: #388E3C;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6" id="function2">
      <div class="input-group" id="input">
        <div class="custom-file">
          <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01" aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
          <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose your p12 file...</label>
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="button" id="cssBtn" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Convert p12 to jks</button>
      <!-- This is the button! -->

    </div>

  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Works for me when i copy your exact html and css into an environment, i would say that it's because you already have a lot of classes attached to the button

```
class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block"
```

you may need to edit some of these classes as they are probably taking priority over the button itself

the best way to know is to do

```
button {
    padding-top: 200px!important;
    background-color: #388E3C;  
}
```

although important is not best practice but that will give you your answer

Comment: I think you are most likely right. As you just mentioned, I just remember that I cannot style my button after I applied btn-block I think

Answer (score 0):

If green button is all you need then add `btn btn-success` instead of `btn btn-primary`

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6" id="function2">
        <div class="input-group" id="input">
            <div class="custom-file">
              <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" id="inputGroupFile01"
                aria-describedby="inputGroupFileAddon01">
              <label class="custom-file-label" for="inputGroupFile01">Choose your p12 file...</label>
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block">Convert p12 to jks</button> <!-- This is the button! -->

    </div>

</div>
```